# What is the max limit of contentImage of NSUserNotification

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, nsimage, nsusernotification

I have a mac app that shows `NSUsernotification` with `contentImage` when the image is downloaded from the URL, however sometimes the Image is of a very large size, at this time the notification does not get delivered and I can see no error message in the downloading task.

Hence is there a limit on the size of the contentImage that can be displayed in the NSUsernotification? may be I am exceeding that and the notification does not show?

Answer (score 0):

NSUserNotification expects the image to have a 44×44 pixel resolution and will scale the image if it has another resolution.
https://blog.timschroeder.net/2014/01/25/os-x-notifications-with-custom-images/